# Showing that $ \mathcal{F}^{-1}((1+|\cdot|^2)^{s/2}\mathcal{F}(u))=(Id-\Delta)^{s/2}(u)$

Tags: sobolev-spaces, fractional-sobolev-spaces

In Sobolev space
$H^{s}(\mathbb{R}^n):=\left\{u\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n:\mathcal{F}^{-1}((1+|\cdot|^2)^{s/2}\mathcal{F}(u))\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)\right\}$

Why $\mathcal{F}^{-1}((1+|\cdot|^2)^{s/2}\mathcal{F}(u))=(Id-\Delta)^{s/2}(u)$?

I know that, if $s=2$, and because $\widehat{\Delta u}=-|\cdot|^2\widehat{u}$ (Fourier transforms properties), then
\begin{align*}|(Id-\Delta)u|_{2}&=|\mathcal{F}(u-\Delta u)|_{2}\\
&=|\widehat{u}-\widehat{\Delta u}|_{2}\\
&=|\widehat{u}-(-|\cdot|^2\widehat{u})|_{2}\\
&=|\widehat{u}+|\cdot|^2\widehat{u}|_{2}\\
&=|(1+|\cdot|^2)\widehat{u}|_{2}
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}|\mathcal{F}^{-1}((1+|\cdot|^2)\mathcal{F}(u))|&=|(1+|\cdot|^2)\widehat{u}|_{2}
\end{align*}
Therefore, $\mathcal{F}^{-1}((1+|\cdot|^2)\mathcal{F}(u))=(Id-\Delta)(u)$

But, Why $\mathcal{F}^{-1}((1+|\cdot|^2)^{s/2}\mathcal{F}(u))=(Id-\Delta)^{s/2}(u)$?  The $s/2$ causes me a problem.

Comment: What is your definition of the power of an operator? If $s = 2n$ is an even integer, then remark that
$$
(1-\Delta)^{n} =  (1-\Delta)(1-\Delta) \dots (1-\Delta) = \mathcal{F}^{-1}(1+|\cdot|^2) \mathcal{F} \mathcal{F}^{-1}(1+|\cdot|^2) \mathcal{F} \dots \mathcal{F}^{-1}(1+|\cdot|^2) \mathcal{F} = \mathcal{F}^{-1}(1+|\cdot|^2)(1+|\cdot|^2) \dots (1+|\cdot|^2) \mathcal{F} = \mathcal{F}^{-1}(1+|\cdot|^2)^n \mathcal{F}
$$
So
$$
(1-\Delta)^{s/2} = \mathcal{F}^{-1}(1+|\cdot|^2)^{s/2} \mathcal{F}
$$

Comment: The truth is that I do not have a precise definition of the power of an operator. I ask it because I have seen this result but they never prove it.